# how it works construction [QueryString("productID")]int? productId (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, query-string

Please tell me what it is, how it works construction
`[QueryString("productID")]int? productId`
Used as a parameter to a function

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("productID")]int? productId)
```

My English is not very good, but I'll try to explain. If I was writing this function I would do this:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct()
{
    int? productId;
    string productIdStr = Request.QueryString["productID"];
    if (productIdStr != null)
        productId = int.Parse(productIdStr);
    else
        productId = null;

     ---------------------------------
}
```

But this code is done so very elegant, but I do not understand what it is

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("productID")]int? productId)
{

}
```

Comment: not able to understand your question, could you please add some detail.

Comment: What library are you using that provides the `QueryString` attribute?  That doesn't exist by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you're using the QueryString attribute that's part of ASP.NET 4.5 web forms model binding.

The attribute is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.querystringattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

This tutorial provides some background: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/using-query-string-values-to-retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

As per looking to code.

you are passing Query string parameter to GetProduct Method.

ueryString("productID")]int? parse ProductID to Integer.

If you have detail code then provide.

Answer (score 0):

Do Like That .. Fisrt Add As Instance in Class Then Yon Not Need To pass it GetProduct ...

```
namespace A
{
    public class B
    {
       string productIdStr1 = Request.QueryString["productID"];
     }
}
}

public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct() 
  {
    int? productId;
    string productIdStr =productIdStr1  ;
    if (productIdStr != null)
        productId = int.Parse(productIdStr);
    else
        productId = null;

    }
```